# LoadingCache mocking for JUnit testing

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I need to test this method.

```
public String getTenantName(String tenantId) {
    var tenant = getTenant(tenantId);
    if (tenant == null) {
      throw new TenantNotFoundException(tenantId);
    }

    return tenant.getTenantname();
  }
```

but I am having problems with mocking the below loading cache

```
  LoadingCache<String, Tenant> tenantCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().maximumSize(1000)
      .expireAfterAccess(24, TimeUnit.HOURS).build(new CacheLoader<String, Tenant>() {
        @Override
        public Tenant load(String tenantId) {
          return tenantClient.getTenant(tenantId);
        }
      });
```

as this is being called by another private method

```
  private Tenant getTenant(String tenantId) {
    try {
      if (StringUtils.isBlank(tenantId)) {
        return null;
      }
      return tenantCache.get(tenantId);
    } catch (TenantNotFoundException | ExecutionException e) {
      logger.error(tenantId, e);
      throw new TenantNotFoundException(tenantId);
    }
  }
```

I would really appreciate some help here.

I mocked loading cache
@mock
LoadingCache<String, Tenant> tenantCache;

and then in my test function I create a tenant object and return that on tenantCache.get() call.

```
tenantCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().maximumSize(1000)
                  .expireAfterAccess(24, TimeUnit.HOURS).build(new CacheLoader<String, Tenant>() {
                      @Override
                      public Tenant load(String tenantId) {
                        return tenantClient.getTenant(tenantId);
                      }
                    });
        
        Map<String, Tenant> map = new HashMap<String, Tenant>();
        map.put("test", tenant);
        tenantCache.putAll(map);
```

also for tenantClient I changed that to return tenant.
return tenantClient.getTenant(id) =>> return tenant;
as tenantClient is calling another API.

Comment: I used reflection to test it successfully but I need to understand mocking to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, LoadingCache appears as a variable inside the service but it is implemented as an anonymous class. Therefore we need to mock LoadingCache and use

```
when(tenantCache.get(anyString())).thenReturn(new Tenant());
```

Comment: Normally LoadingCache would be a private property of a class.  A class would then have public methods that would put <k,v> pairs into the cache, get them or invalidate cache.  How would you test it in that case?  Thanks @Harsh